# std::process:Command not returning Err() result when using 'bash -c'

Tags: bash, command-line, rust

I'm trying to understand why I'm not getting an `Err()` result when using `bash -c` expression to run a command.

Here is an example and the output below. I expect **`out2`** and **`out3`** to be an `Err()` but **`out3`** is an `Ok()` with the failed status.

I'm using `bash -c` to execute a command from a given string, which is easy.

It's possible to get an `Err()` result using `bash -c` syntax?

```rust
#![allow(unused)]

use std::process::{Command, Output};

fn main() {
    let out1 = Command::new("bash").arg("-c").arg("ls").output();
    println!("out1: {:?}", out1);

    let out2 = Command::new("wrongcommand").arg("-c").arg("ls").output();
    println!("out2: {:?}", out2);

    let out3 = Command::new("bash").arg("-c").arg("wrongcommand").output();
    println!("out3: {:?}", out3);
}
```

Output:

```
out1: Ok(Output { status: ExitStatus(ExitStatus(0)), stdout: "Cargo.lock\nCargo.toml\ncrate-information.json\nsrc\ntarget\n", stderr: "" })
out2: Err(Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" })
out3: Ok(Output { status: ExitStatus(ExitStatus(32512)), stdout: "", stderr: "bash: wrongcommand: command not found\n" })
```

I tried from command line and

```
$ bash -c wrongcommand
```

and

```
$ wrongcommand
```

and both return the same exit code (127). That's why I expected that Command failed in the same way.

Comment: Edited my answer a bit, added more info on how to catch and redirect that spurious `Ok`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That can be explained pretty easily. Follow along on the [list of error codes](https://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html)

`out1` is `Ok` for obvious reasons

`out2` is an `Err` type because `Command` directly looked for the process, could not find it, and returned `ENOENT` (code 2). This error happened *within* rust, nothing was actually executed.

`out3` is `Ok` because the process that `Command` ran is `bash`, and it returned its status. In this case, it wouldn't have found the command, so by bash statuses, it'll have returned 127. However, it's not that easy, because there is an additional layer of information contained in `ExitStatus`. On unix, when a process fails, it actually returns a 16bit/32bit integer (based on platform/libc/etc), separated in two:

- The highest bits are what signal triggered the return
- The lowest 8 bits are the return status of the process

And, to no surprise, if we shift 32512 8 bits to the right (it was an `u16`), we get... 127!

The takeaway is simple:

- `Err` **definitely** means the process didn't run
- `Ok` means the main process ran, but you'll need to check `ExitStatus::success()` to confirm that it actually did (i.e. 0 as exit status)

You could recover it like so:

```
Command::new("bash").arg("-c").arg("wrongcommand").output().and_then(|r| match r.status.success() {
  true => Ok(r),
  false => Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::InvalidData, "Process error"))
});
```

You can play with this on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3c62f1ad0d60614834bb25e39d0d2862). `success()` is a decently reliable indicator of child process success; all it does is check if the least significant 8 bits of the exit status is non-zero.

Obviously, this does not help if a process returns non-zero on success, but that's a different problem.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Yes, I did realize bash was the command returning the status. My confusion was that in the terminal, both ways returned 127 so I expected the same behavior. Now, I wrapped the command execution and return Ok() or Err() depending on status.

Comment: All good then :-) just remember, if you do need the status, you can retrieve it back with a bit shift